# Find all rows with timestamp range inside of another timestamp range

Tags: php, mysql

I need to select all rows where `start` and `due` columns range falls into another range. All times are given in unix timestamp format.

The following query works, except when `start` < `:weekstart` or `due` > `:weekend`.

```
$week_start = (new DateTimeImmutable())->setTimestamp($_REQUEST['startdatets']);
$week_start_ts = $week_start->getTimestamp();
$week_end = $week_start->modify('+6 days')->setTime(23,59,59);
$week_end_ts = $week_end->getTimestamp();

$query = "  SELECT *

        FROM        schedules

        WHERE       ((start BETWEEN :weekstart AND :weekend) OR (due BETWEEN :weekstart AND :weekend))

        ORDER BY    start
";
try { $stmt = $dbh->prepare($query); $stmt->execute(array(':weekstart' => $week_start_ts, ':weekend' => $week_end_ts)); } catch(PDOException $ex) { echo 'Query failed: ' . $ex->getMessage(); exit; }
```

[image]

I need both to work if possible
Please help.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determine Whether Two Date Ranges Overlap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/325933/determine-whether-two-date-ranges-overlap)

Comment: I voted to close this question as unclear what you are asking.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: what exactly was unclear? I clearly specified what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahh, so you you're missing cases where both `start < :weekstart` AND `end > :weekend` - neither is in between, but the week overlaps the range. There's a nice logic for it.

Search for periods `WHERE start < :weekend AND end > :weekstart`

Comment: You sure? Look carefully what is compared.

Comment: This will work, just try it. Check duplicate link for detail explanation.